# Setting session variable on click

Tags: django, django-views

I've got a popup message with a close button at the top. If the user clicks the close button, they should never see the message again while on the site. If they don't click the close button, they will see it on the top of each page on the site.

When the user clicks the close button, I want to set request.session['promo'] to 0. On subsequent page loads on the site, if request.session['promo'] == 0, I will not show the popup message.

What is the best way of setting a session variable on click in django?

Thanks for the direction!

Answer (score 1):

In HTML OnClick of button just call a function in views.py
Ex:
**IN HTML :**`<Button onclick={% your_fucntion %}></button>`

**IN VIEWS.PY :**

```
def your_fucntion(request):
                  request.session['promo'] == 'your_variable'
```

**for getting variable :**

```
promo = request.session['promo']
```

Comment: this is what i've done, but it requires that I reload the page.

Comment: @JasonHoward then you need to do this with AJAX, refer https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Comment: Go with AJAX and set action to false .You must have used forms in your HTML

Comment: If you got your ans can you just click on the right click. Appreciated .